# simplify or Refactored nested foreach loops

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, nested-loops

I am new to c# and trying to simplify below code

can someone help me simplify this code without breaking the code-flow.

Below is the code snippet where I have 5 foreach loops at nested levels.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
var rows = new List<TBRow>();
        foreach (var rowData in _inputData.TBFlat)
        {
            foreach (var data in rowData)
            {
                if (data.Details != null)
                {
                    foreach (var tLevel in data.Details)
                    {
                        if (tLevel.Details != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var ruLevel in tLevel.Details)
                            {
                                if (ruLevel.Details != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (var acLevel in ruLevel.Details)
                                    {
                                        row = //Operation1
                                        rows.Add(row);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    row = //Operation2
                                    rows.Add(row);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            row = //Operation3
                            rows.Add(row);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    row = //Operation4
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I know a little bit as I am new to c#. can you give me a solution for the above code snippet with functions.

Comment: `foreach (var item in items) DoSomething(item);`

Comment: It's better to provide more information. For example, what are you trying to do here? Why this logic is necessary? What are the operations and why do you create a new row every time? Also, what are the types of your foreach variables? There is such thing as cyclomatic complexity of the code, and, your code would definitely need to satisfy it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what you need, and what can be done (without Operation's and sample data), maybe this help you:

```
class SimplifyOrRefactoredNestedForeachLoops {
    public class TBRow {}

    public interface IGetTBRow {
        TBRow GetRow();
    }        
    
    public abstract class LvlWithDetails<T> :IGetTBRow {
        public T[] Details;

        public virtual TBRow GetRow() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Lvl1 :LvlWithDetails<Lvl2> {}

    public class Lvl2 :LvlWithDetails<Lvl3> {}

    public class Lvl3 :LvlWithDetails<Lvl4> {}

    public class Lvl4 :IGetTBRow {
        public TBRow GetRow() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Tinput {
        public Lvl1[][] TBFlat;
    }

    IEnumerable<TBRow> GetIDontKnowWhatButFlat(Tinput _inputData) {
        foreach(var rowData in _inputData.TBFlat) {
            foreach(var data in rowData) {
                if(data.Details != null) {
                    foreach(var tLevel in data.Details) {
                        if(tLevel.Details != null) {
                            foreach(var ruLevel in tLevel.Details) {
                                if(ruLevel.Details != null) {
                                    foreach(var acLevel in ruLevel.Details) {
                                        yield return acLevel.GetRow();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    yield return ruLevel.GetRow();
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            yield return tLevel.GetRow();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    yield return data.GetRow();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```